# How to match time series in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have two high frequency time series of 3 months worth of data.
The problem is that one goes from 15:30 to 23:00, the other from 01:00 to 00:00.
IS there any way to match the two time series, by discarding the extra data, in order to run some regression analysis?

Comment: match by `scipy.spatial.distance` on overlapping time intervals. or regression if you prefer comovements

Answer (score 0):

use can use the function `combine_first` of pandas Series. This function selects the element of the calling object, if both series contain the same index.
Following code shows a minimum example:

```
idx1 = pd.date_range('2018-01-01', periods=5, freq='H')
idx2 = pd.date_range('2018-01-01 01:00', periods=5, freq='H')

ts1 = pd.Series(range(len(ts1)), index=idx1)
ts2 = pd.Series(range(len(ts2)), index=idx2)

idx1.combine_first(idx2)
```

This gives a dataframe with the content:

```
2018-01-01 00:00:00    0.0
2018-01-01 01:00:00    1.0
2018-01-01 02:00:00    2.0
2018-01-01 03:00:00    3.0
2018-01-01 04:00:00    4.0
2018-01-01 05:00:00    4.0
```

For more complex combinations you can use `combine`.

Comment: Show example code gives you upvoters more quickly. EoR.